# NVD3 example chart not showing

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, nvd3.js

I must be missing something basic... I have copied the exact code for an nvd3 example and even though I'm not getting any error messages, i'm getting a blank page. Both nvd3 and d3 libraries are showing up when I type in "nv" or "d3" in the console, so I don't think I've called them incorrectly.

```
<html>
<body> 
<link href="nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="nv.d3.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript'>

nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
                .showDistX(true)    //showDist, when true, will display those little distribution lines on the axis.
                .showDistY(true)
                .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

  //Configure how the tooltip looks.
  chart.tooltipContent(function(key) {
      return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>';
  });

  //Axis settings
  chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));
  chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));


  var myData = randomData(4,40);
  d3.select('#chart svg')
      .datum(myData)
      .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});


/**************************************
 * Simple test data generator
 */
function randomData(groups, points) { //# groups,# points per group
  var data = [],
      shapes = ['circle', 'cross', 'triangle-up', 'triangle-down', 'diamond', 'square'],
      random = d3.random.normal();

  for (i = 0; i < groups; i++) {
    data.push({
      key: 'Group ' + i,
      values: []
    });

    for (j = 0; j < points; j++) {
      data[i].values.push({
        x: random()
      , y: random()
      , size: Math.random()   //Configure the size of each scatter point
      , shape: (Math.random() > 0.95) ? shapes[j % 6] : "circle"  //Configure the shape of each scatter point.
      });
    }
  }

  return data;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't got a DOM element to append the chart to.  You `select` `'#chart svg'`, but there is no element in your HTML that will match, thus the chart will never get displayed, since it's not getting inserted into the DOM.

This will work...

```
<html>
<body> 
<link href="nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div id="chart"><svg></svg></div>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="nv.d3.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript'>

nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
                .showDistX(true)    //showDist, when true, will display those little distribution lines on the axis.
                .showDistY(true)
                .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

  //Configure how the tooltip looks.
  chart.tooltipContent(function(key) {
      return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>';
  });

  //Axis settings
  chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));
  chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));


  var myData = randomData(4,40);
  d3.select('#chart svg')
      .datum(myData)
      .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});


/**************************************
 * Simple test data generator
 */
function randomData(groups, points) { //# groups,# points per group
  var data = [],
      shapes = ['circle', 'cross', 'triangle-up', 'triangle-down', 'diamond', 'square'],
      random = d3.random.normal();

  for (i = 0; i < groups; i++) {
    data.push({
      key: 'Group ' + i,
      values: []
    });

    for (j = 0; j < points; j++) {
      data[i].values.push({
        x: random()
      , y: random()
      , size: Math.random()   //Configure the size of each scatter point
      , shape: (Math.random() > 0.95) ? shapes[j % 6] : "circle"  //Configure the shape of each scatter point.
      });
    }
  }

  return data;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The only difference is the addition of `<div id="chart"><svg></svg></div>` before your `script` elements.